# Running Romex into a stud wall under a beam

Tags: electrical

How can I run Romex into the stud wall under the beam.  This portion of stud wall will remain unfinished.  Romex will run in the same direction as plumbing.  Can the Romex just go on surface of beam, past the wall top plate and then into wall cavity?
Does in need to be in flexible conduit?
What is best way?
[[image: pic of wallclose up of beam and stud wall]

Comment: Wires below 8 feet need to be protected(from people doing chin ups, pole dances).  Most people just use drywall/plywood for the protection, but if not covered by a wall covering, you need conduit.  Cable(romex) is hard to pull though conduit so people prefer to use THHN/THHW wires to use.

Comment: When you say "beam" do you really mean "joist?"  It would really be helpful if you *sketched* your proposed path...

Comment: Which beam are you talking about?    You want your cable to run along the ceiling and then under the stairs just like the three pipes on the right?   Is that correct?  Can you better describe what kind of joists you have there and their instructions?  Can you drill or punch holes in them? They do not look solid nor like I-joists, I have never seen joists like that. Also what is the diagonal structure there? It's not stairs, right?

Comment: Instead of asking the same question twice, please edit your [previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/283881/running-romex-into-a-stud-wall-that-sits-under-double-2x10-laminated-beam). With the addition of pics (actually getting the images in there), your other question will be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Rules for exposed NM cable (including Romex brand) are pretty strict.

> **334.15(B) Protection from Physical Damage.** Cable shall be protected from physical damage where necessary by rigid metal conduit,
> intermediate metal conduit, electrical metallic tubing, Schedule 80
> PVC conduit, Type RTRC marked with the suffix -XW, or other approved
> means...

Some jurisdictions add 7 or 8' restrictions to the above section.

> **NEC 334.15(C) In Unfinished Basements and Crawl Spaces.** Where cable is
> run at angles with joists in unfinished basements, it shall be
> permissible to secure cables not smaller than two 6 AWG or three 8 AWG
> conductors directly to the lower edges of the joists. *Smaller cables
> shall be run either through bored holes in joists or on running
> boards.* Nonmetallic-sheathed cable installed on the wall of an
> unfinished basement shall be permitted to be installed in a listed
> conduit or tubing or shall be protected in accordance with 300.4.
> Conduit or tubing shall be provided with a suitable insulating bushing
> or adapter at the point the cable enters the raceway. The sheath of
> the nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall extend through the conduit or
> tubing and into the outlet or device box not less than 6 mm (1∕4 in.).
> The cable shall be secured within 300 mm (12 in.) of the point where
> the cable enters the conduit or tubing. Metal conduit, tubing, and
> metal outlet boxes shall be connected to an equipment grounding
> conductor complying with the provisions of 250.86 and 250.148.

I understand symmetry is nice, but it may be best to look for a different route to keep the cable up in protected space.

Your joists look like a manufactured product, look for manufacturers marking on joists and visit their website for drilling clearances.